# K Group Determined by Chern Classes

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes, k-theory, topological-k-theory

Why is it that the complex reduced K group of $\mathbb{CP}^2$ is determined by Chern classes $c_1$ and $c_2$?

I am aware of the fact that the cohomology ring of complex Grassmannians is generated by Chern classes up to its dimension. How does this relate to my question? Or am I heading the wrong way?

Comment: @Con But the result is about Cohomology ring…not K group, I guess? Or do they have some relation? Thanks!

Comment: I would imagine that this is related to the fact that the Chern character is an isomorphism $\text{ch}:K(X)\otimes\mathbb{Q}\to H^\text{ev}(X,\mathbb{Q})$. But I'm not sure on the details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complex vector bundles over a CW complex $X$ with $\dim X \leq 4$ (e.g. $X = \mathbb{CP}^2$) are determined up to isomorphism by their rank and Chern classes. More precisely, if $\operatorname{Vect}_r^{\mathbb{C}}(X)$ denotes isomorphism classes of rank $r$ complex vector bundles on $X$, then

$$c_1 : \operatorname{Vect}^{\mathbb{C}}_1(X) \to H^2(X; \mathbb{Z})$$

is a bijection, and for every $r > 1$,

$$(c_1, c_2) : \operatorname{Vect}_r^{\mathbb{C}}(X) \to H^2(X; \mathbb{Z})\times H^4(X; \mathbb{Z})$$

is a bijection. See [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/422216/21564) for a proof.

In particular, two complex vector bundles over $X$ are stably isomorphic if and only if they have the same Chern classes. Therefore, the map $(c_1, c_2) : \widetilde{K}(X) \to H^2(X; \mathbb{Z})\times H^4(X;\mathbb{Z})$ is a bijection.